# Create C-style array form parameter pack

Tags: c++, arrays, parameter-pack

How can I create an array from the parameter pack?

```
    template<typename T, typename... Tpack>
    void covert(Tpack ...pack){
        T *arr = new T[???]; //TODO: how to get Tpack size?
        // TODO: how to fill array?
    }
```

Comment: `sizeof...(Tpack)`?

Comment: How to fill the array with what? You made an array of `T`, but `pack` could have various different types.

Comment: Is `Tpack` supposed to be a pack of types or should it really be `T... Tpack` in the template parameter list?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem: what are you actually trying to achieve? Maybe there's a better way to solve it...

Comment: You an use `sizeof...(pack)` to get the number of elements in the pack, but I would forget about the array entirely and just use `std::vector<T> arr{pack...};`.

Comment: thanks for the comments, I'm trying to figure out the parameter pack. This is a simple practice example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do:

```
template<typename T, typename... Tpack>
void covert(Tpack ...pack){
    T *arr = new T[sizeof...(Tpack)]{pack...};
    // ...
    delete[] arr;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bK33nnM78)

but your function is strange as-is.
`std::tuple` might be more appropriate, or change input parameter to `std::initializer_list<T>` or `std::array<T, N>`.

Comment: Mr. quick answer man.... it's not even clear what the OP wants to achieve... I mean, why not just do something like `int t[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };`

Comment: I want to call the function like this: convert<int> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Comment: @JHBonarius: We ask for MCVE, and OP provides it and question is answerable. That reduction might make the example with poor meaning, I agree. And so now we can speculate about what OP really wants.